# Sitemap on dynamic generated content

Tags: indexing, seo, web-crawler, sitemap, dynamic-data

I'd need to index my website on Google and other search engines, though my website is a database of IP addresses and the webpage is dynamically generated like

```
example.com/show.php?&ip=ipvalue
```

Would it be possible to index on Google and other search engines every IP address I have on the database by linking directly the direct URL as showed above?

I know how to set up a proper sitemap file to index static content though I cannot understand how I could tell a search engine to index a URL that doesn't physically exist unless the user passes a value which is in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one (neither human visitors nor search engine bots) knows if a document is created dynamically or if it exists as a static file.

A search engine would have no reason to handle a link to `http://example.com/show.php?ip=127.0.0.1` differently from a link to `http://example.com/ip/127.0.0.1`. By using URL rewriting (e.g., mod_rewrite for Apache), you could rewrite your URLs in such a way.

So: Just *link* to these pages from a place that search engine crawlers can access.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I tried to go with a dynamically generated sitemap writing inside all the links to the IPs I have in my database. I have a script that updates the sitemap every day and add the new URLs in the format: http://example.com/show.php?ip=127.0.0.1. Does it male sense to you at all?

Comment: @user4386850: Yes, there’s nothing special about this, it’s very common. -- Personally, I’d rewrite the URLs to something like `http://example.com/ip/127.0.0.1`, as "show" doesn’t seem to be important information for your visitors, ".php" is not useful either (no need for visitors to learn about your backend programming; and might become confusing if you change programming languages), and using a query component is not as beautiful and probably not as easy for not so savvy users as using slash-separated path segments.